# How to change $.ajax() default settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I modify the default values of options for the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function?

Ideally to do something similar to:

```
//set ajax async to false
$(someSelector).load(url, data, function(){});
//set ajax async to true
```

to allow me to carry out `.post()` synchronously.

Comment: **Note to all:** Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated. Do not use this approach.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want [**ajaxSetup**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
   url: "/xmlhttp/",
   global: false,
   type: "POST"

 });
 $.ajax({ data: myData });
```

Answer (score 23):

Try using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

Comment: Doing this gave me the following message: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.