# AJAX call to PHP script not working in IE

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer

What worked:

My code works across all browsers now and looks like this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
});


 $.post('./archive_onBeforeUnload.php?', {contact_id: contact_id}, function(){
 }).error(function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
    }); 
 }
```

Setting `async` to be false within `$.post()` didn't seem to be enough for it to work for me.  I had to put that setting in `$.ajaxSetup` for it to work across all browsers.

---

My project is a sort of chat program that I created using HTML and PHP.  The issue that I'm having is that if the person closes the window using the X button at the top, there is some PHP that I need to run in order for my program to still run properly.  So I did some searching and ended up with this bit of code in:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $.post('./archive_onBeforeUnload.php?', {contact_id: contact_id}, function(){
    }).error(function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

This calls the archive_beforeUnload.php and runs the little amount of PHP that I need it to.  In FireFox, Safari, and Chrome this runs just fine but in IE I seem to have an issue.  There doesn't seem to be enough time for IE to actually fully complete the call which messes up the rest of my program a bit.  A way that I have around this is to use add a return statement like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $.post('./archive_onBeforeUnload.php?', {async: 'true', cache: 'false', contact_id: contact_id}, function(){
    }).error(function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    });
    return 'I need to fix the timer here.  Without this it doesn\'t work in IE';
}
```

This seems to give IE enough time to actually complete the AJAX call.  The thing is, it creates a confirmation window before the window closes every single time, which will get annoying for the user.  Is there some way that I can get this working in IE without the need for the return statement?  I've looked around the web quite a bit but have yet to find something that works for me.

Hopefully I've been clear enough in my issue.

Edit:

Thought I should maybe add my PHP script:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('client_init.php');

$sqlRequeue = 'UPDATE S2G_CHAT_TRAVELLER_QUEUE SET';
$sqlRequeue .= ' isOpen = 1';
$sqlRequeue .= ' WHERE contactID='.$contact_id;
$resRequeue = $conn_dd->query($sqlRequeue);
$resRequeue->close;

$_SESSION['s2g_chat_messages_shown'] = $default_messages_shown;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `$.post()` is asynchronous, so the function returns before it completes.

It looks like you can use the `$.async()` function to [do the same call synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re).

EDIT: Or you can [change the default AJAX settings to be synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849686/how-to-change-ajax-default-settings).

Comment: Wow... I've set 'async' to be both true and false and it did nothing.  I've even used $.ajaxSetup() before to no avail, I'd even fallen on the exact post you linked to.  This time I seem to have gotten lucky and it's working.  Thank you.  I'll edit my code up top to reflect what works for me.

Comment: @Francis - I don't think `async` is an option to `$.post`, only to `$.async`.

Comment: Oh
... That I didn't know.  This whole project is my first time working with AJAX so it's been quite a learning experience.